# Sequence of $\infty$-norms of powers of a matrix

Tags: sequences-and-series, matrices

Given a matrix $A \in R^{n \times n}$ with $\rho(A)<1$ (all eigen values strictly inside the unit circle),

how does the sequence $\{||A^k||_{\infty},k \geq 1\}$ converge?

For some matrix $M \in R^{n \times n}$, $||M||_{\infty}$ denotes the usual matrix $\infty$-norm defined as
$$||M||_{\infty}=\max_{i=1,\cdots,n} \sum_{j=1}^n |M_{ij}|$$

It is clear that $\lim_{k \to \infty} ||A^k||_{\infty} = 0$.
However I am unable to understand how to characterize the convergence to $0$.

Thanks you vey much.

Comment: the infinity norm is submultiplicative, so you can deduce it from the Jordan form